# Performance Counters - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, iis, perfmon

We are seeing request queueing on our front end web servers yet Request Wait Time metric is zero (which seems counterintuitive)

So I'm looking to trace Request Wait Time.. and I see that there are up to 6 available counters for Request Wait Time; namely

- ASP.NET/Request Wait Time
- ASP.NET v2.0.50727/Request Wait Time
- ASP.NET v4.0.30319/Request Wait Time
- ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319/Request Wait Time
- ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727/Request Wait Time
- ASP.NET Applications/Request Wait Time

Is ASP.NET/Request Wait Time a super set of the rest?